# OpenMP/fortran shared variables in a function become "undefined"

Tags: function, fortran, openmp

The fortran code below is a minimal working example of a much larger code I am trying to run. The code runs fine in serial, but crashes if run in parallel. My understanding is that the function cannot "receive" properly the shared variables gcash and indcash ...

Is there a solution to this? Or should I just re-think the problem from scratch? The problem should be possible to parallelize.

```
program simple_test
    
use omp_lib    
    
real, allocatable :: gcash(:,:)
real, allocatable :: endresult(:,:)
real :: output
real :: arg
integer :: indcash 
integer :: n_cash = 3

allocate(gcash(n_cash,1))
allocate(endresult(n_cash,1))

gcash(1,1) = 1
gcash(2,1) = 2
gcash(3,1) = 3

arg = 3

!$omp parallel do default(private) shared(end_result,n_cash,arg,gcash)
do indcash = 1,n_cash
    
    output= fun(arg)
    endresult(indcash,1) = output
end do
!$omp end parallel do


    contains
    
     function fun(X) result(F)
        real, intent(in) :: x
        real :: F
        
        aux = gcash(indcash,1)*2+X
        F = aux
        
     end function fun 
    
     
end program
```

Comment: First things first, `Implicit None` will show you at least 1 bug. But next please tell us what compiler you are using. I have half a memory of something like this with gfortran here before.

Answer (score 1):

The `indcash` variable is private in the OpenMP region, that is, the compiler creates a temporary instance for each thread.

The function `fun()` tries accessing the `indcash` variable as well, but when compiling `fun()` the compiler refers to the original global instance of `indcash`, not to the private instances. And if you think about it, this is normal, as this fucntion could also be called from outside of the OpenMP region.

So, this code cannot work. You have (at least) to pass `indcash` in the function arguments.

But the more general recommandation is to not rely on host association and global variables when using OpenMP: this is highly error prone. Instead, pass all the variables that are needed by the function, in the function arguments.

Comment: Upvote for  simply "But the more general recommandation is to not rely on host association and global variables." Even without OMP don't do it. Keep your subprograms pure!